# import .xls and get sheet by number

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I've been researching all morning and can't find a working solution.  I was hoping somebody can tell me the answer.

I am having a user upload a .xls file using a FileUpload, then I want to select all the data from 4 sheets and put in 4 separate datasets.  Here is the code I am using:

```
string strConn = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM [{0}]";

    DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, strConn);
```

So I have 2 questions,

First Question: How can I select a sheet without knowing its name?  The above code is not working, If I substitute {0} with MyFirstSheet$ then it works.  I need to know how to select without me knowing what the name will be.  Error that I get is:

```
ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '0}'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

Second Question: Is there a way to select all 4 at once and have them put in 4 separate data sets?  Currently i was planing to read the file 4 times.

Suggested Code:

```
String connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    String sheet = conn.GetSchema("Tables").Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    String selectCommand = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet);
    DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(selectCommand, "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    da.Fill(excelDataSet);

    btnLoadCsv.Text = excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[10][1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a collection of sheets from the workbook:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
conn.Open();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in conn.GetSchema("Tables").Rows)
    sb.Append(String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM [{0}];", row["TABLE_NAME"]);
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sb.ToString(), conn);
DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
da.Fill(excelDataSet);
excelDataSet.Tables[0].Name = "myTable1";
excelDataSet.Tables[1].Name = "myTable2";
excelDataSet.Tables[2].Name = "myTable3";
//etc...however many sheets you got from Excel (you could loop this too)
```

This example loops over the row in the schema for "Tables", which equates to sheets in the workbook.  Using a compounded SQL `SELECT`, you get all tables at once into the `DataSet`, which you can either reference by index (`excelDataSet.Tables[0]`), or by name if you assign one.

Comment: Could you tell me, how could I loop this, so that it would store in the same DataSet all 4 tables?  I am a little confused by the code.

Comment: I also get an error when running your code: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.  What would be the provider I use?

Comment: The connection string is specific to the driver you are using (have installed).  Here's an example of the latest one I used:  `String connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1""";`.  Of course, replace `{0}` with your filename.

Comment: I should point out that that connection string example works for my local installation of Excel 2007.  There are, of course, later versions that require difference references.

Comment: k so I'm having troubles with your approach.  I edited my question to include the code I just ran, if you can tell me why am I getting 1 always no matter what row/column I select from it.

Comment: What is in the Excel sheet as data?  Because that selection you are doing is getting the `Cell` data (in that specific example, it would be cell reference `B11`.

Comment: Perhaps it's a formatting issue, then.  I don't think I can answer that part of it without the Excel sheet.  Since you said the data is "0019" I assume it's either non-numeric, or has formatting applied.  I suppose that could affect what is actually selected into the table.  You could use `Type t = excelDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[1].DataType` to determine what type the column thinks it has and convert appropriately to the type you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try excel data reader, which is an open source project on codeplex? You can view/download the library here http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/. What you would need to do is get the stream from the FileUploader, and pass it to the library.

The following is a sample extract of the code required

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
//...
//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
//...
//3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
//...
//4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

//5. Data Reader methods
while (excelReader.Read())
{
//excelReader.GetInt32(0);
}

//6. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
excelReader.Close();
```

Below, is the code that loads all sheets into several data tables in one dataset.

```
//3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

Comment: So what is bad about the way that I am doing it?, that is why is Odbc a wrong way to do it?

Comment: Does ExcelDataReader use Office Interop? If so, then it cannot be used in an ASP.NET application.